# Blender does not correctly show interface text

Tags: interface

I have installed Blender 3.5 on an old laptop: MacBookPro from 2010 on which i currently run Linux Manjaro. For some reason the interface text is not showing correctly. Here's the screenshot

[image]

As you can see, the text is not showing at all and computer is very old. Below I list a few specification details.

Video:

```
Device-1: NVIDIA G96CM [GeForce 9600M GT] driver: nouveau v: kernel
Device-2: NVIDIA C79 [GeForce 9400M] driver: nouveau v: kernel
```

CPU:

```
Info: dual core model: Intel Core2 Duo T9600 bits: 64 type: MCP cache:
  L2: 6 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 1815 min/max: 1596/2793 cores: 1: 1874 2: 1756
```

Memory:

```
RAM: total: 3.59 GiB used: 2.61 GiB (72.8%)
```

Do you think the issue is related to an old computer?

Thanks

Comment: Hii, Celdor, Thanks for a well constructed question, but I'm afraid it isn't in the remit of Blender SE: it doesn't concern a problem in  the normal _use_ of the application. It's a configuration problem. or a bug. All I can suggest to narrow it down is to see if the fault still occurs in earlier versions Blender, having checked your GPU drivers, and to make a bug report if not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GPU alone is far from Blender's requirements, so yeah... Probably an old computer for doing anything modern 3D.

From [Requirements — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/):

> #### Hardware Requirements
>
> ###### Minimum
>
> - 64-bit quad core CPU with SSE2 support
> - 8 GB RAM
> - Full HD display
> - Mouse, trackpad or pen+tablet
> - Graphics card with 2 GB RAM, OpenGL 4.3
> - [Less than 10 year old](https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2013-January/039014.html)
>   [...]
>   NVIDIA
>   GeForce 400 and newer, Quadro Tesla GPU architecture and newer, including RTX-based cards, with NVIDIA drivers (list of all GeForce and Quadro GPUs)

From [NVIDIA GeForce 9600M GT Specs | TechPowerUp GPU Database](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-9600m-gt.c1518):

> - OpenGL 3.3
> - Memory Size 512 MB
> - Release Date Jun 4th, 2008 [almost 15 years old, and 2 years older than the first GT 400s]

You could probably use Blender v2.79 as it only requires OpenGL 2.1. Though you won't go far anyway, at least you might be able to use it.

Download it there: [Previous Versions — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I hoped I could manage just to run Blender with some basic tutorials on UI to get familiar with elementary stuff. I should have known 3D requires relatively new hardware. Cheers.

Comment: @Celdor It's not that 3D in general requires new hardware. Old games can run on old computers, newer games need newer computers. As L0Lock suggests you could try to use older versions of Blender. Like in all software, the problem might be that it lacks features that newer versions have or there are changes in UI and shortcouts etc. But this is not a specific 3D software issue. And the problem is, even if you want to do just elementary stuff - there is no "I only want to do basic modeling" mode to start Blender, like there is no "I only want to paint with the brush" mode when opening Photoshop.